# Consecutive averages in Access grouped by identifying factors

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, left-join, average

I have a table in an access database with the following fields: "Period" (as YYYYMM, so e.g. 202111, 202112, 202201 and so on), ID (a 'short text field' identifier), Instrument (a 'short text field' describing an instrument ID key) and, lastly, a dollar amount as field "Volume Balance". Clearly, in reality, there are many more IDs and different Instrument keys than just 3, resp. 2, as in the example below. The goal is now to calculate a simple average for every two consecutive months like the bottom table (exemplary numbers, unit is USD) per ID and per instrument. That is to say, one ID can have multiple entries in the same month for different Instrument keys (in the below table, ID 1 and 3 have balances in two different instruments A and B, while ID 2 only has a balance in instrument B).

Input -->

| Period | ID | Instrument | Volume Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 202101 | 2 | B | 2 |
| 202101 | 3 | A | 3 |
| 202102 | 1 | A | 4 |
| 202102 | 1 | B | 5 |
| 202102 | 2 | B | 6 |
| 202102 | 3 | A | 7 |
| 202103 | 1 | A | 8 |
| 202103 | 2 | B | 9 |
| 202103 | 3 | A | 10 |
| 202103 | 3 | B | 11 |

Desired Result (essentially a glamorized Pivot table) -->

| Period | ID | Instrument | Average Volume Balance | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 1 | A | 0.5 | `(Jan balance / 2)` since no prior data point for Instrument & ID combination |
| 202101 | 2 | B | 1 | `(Jan balance / 2)` since no prior data point for Instrument & ID combination |
| 202101 | 3 | A | 1.5 | `(Jan balance / 2)` since no prior data point for Instrument & ID combination |
| 202102 | 1 | A | 2.5 | `(Jan + Feb balance for this specific ID & Instrument combo / 2)` |
| 202102 | 1 | B | 2.5 | `(Feb balance / 2)` since no prior data point for Instrument & ID combination |
| 202102 | 2 | B | 4 | `(Jan + Feb balance for this specific ID & Instrument combo / 2)` |
| 202102 | 3 | A | 5 | `(Jan + Feb balance for this specific ID & Instrument combo / 2)` |
| 202103 | 1 | A | 6 | `(Feb + Mar balance for this specific ID & Instrument combo / 2)` |
| 202103 | 2 | B | 7.5 | `(Jan + Feb balance for this specific ID & Instrument combo / 2)` |
| 202103 | 3 | A | 8.5 | `(Jan + Feb balance for this specific ID & Instrument combo / 2)` |
| 202103 | 3 | B | 5.5 | `(Mar balance / 2)` since no prior data point for Instrument & ID combination |

I have played around with the DAvg function but the consecutive period cut-offs and grouping are fatal for me. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is the combination of Period, ID and Instrument unique in the table?

Comment: Yessir! That is correct. Each ID&Instrument&Period only appears once in the table / is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self `LEFT` join:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (t1.[Volume Balance] + Nz(t2.[Volume Balance])) / 2 AS [Average Volume Balance]
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Format(DateAdd('m', 1, CDate(Format(MAX(Period) + '01', '0000-00-00'))), 'yyyymm'), ID, Instrument, 0
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY ID, Instrument
) AS t1 LEFT JOIN tablename AS t2
ON DateAdd('m', 1, CDate(Format(t2.Period + '01', '0000-00-00'))) = CDate(Format(t1.Period + '01', '0000-00-00'))
AND t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Instrument = t1.Instrument
ORDER BY t1.ID, t1.Instrument, t1.Period;
```

Comment: Forpas, you genius! This works great, thank you so very much for everything. Just one quick follow-up question. The above excludes those cases where there is only one data point for the (month1+month2)/2 calculation. So, for example, if only month 202111 is populated, but no 202112 balance, I would still like to show the 202111/2 (as in, stipulate the empty month is 0 balance) as 202112. Similarly, if 202112 is non-nill, but 202111 is empty (e.g. because it has just been bought into), I would like to show 202112/2 as 202112. Is that theoretically also possible (maybe as an iferror-type clause?

Comment: @DVEF the code as it is, in each row it calculates the average of the current and previous period of the same id and instrument and if there is no previous period it just divides by 2 the current Volume Balance, because NZ() returns 0. This happens with the first period where there is no previous period and this would happen for any period for which there is no row with the previous period for the same id and instrument. Isn't this what yo asked?

Comment: Yes, and it does that computation perfectly. What I noticed, however, is that at the beginning and end of a period of holdings / balances, it would omit those averages where one of the two inputs for the average is not available. Say, our records for a specific ID&Instrument combo start at April 2021 and end at September 2021, then the first average I receive using above code would be for May 2021 and the last one is for September 2021, when we would need to also receive those for April and October as half the April and September data.

Comment: This is likely because our raw data, instead of having a record for this period which stipulates 0, does not have a record at all. So, there is no March 2021 data which says ID XYZ for Instrument IDK is 0, but instead, there is no trace of this whatsoever. In an Excel pivot, this is filled automatically if a period is unavailable. I guess I will need to pre-put a query which fills all non-available periods as 0 for it to work as intended :)?

Comment: @DVEF for the sample data that you posted my query returns your expected results as they are. Edit your sample data to cover the case you are referring to and your expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: OK, so essentially this: Say we only have ID 1 and one instrument (e.g. A) for only two periods of the year, 202102 and 202103. Holdings are USD10,000,000 for both these periods. Since I want my calculation to be (current month + prior month)/2, the code piece returns the correct result for 202102 (i.e. half of the holding = USD5,000,000) and 202103 (10,000,000). However, I would also want to have the formula I mention above carried on to current month +1, so that for 202104, it also returns USD5,000,000 (202103: USD10,000,000 plus 202104: USD0 over two).

Comment: I suppose the alternative way would be to fill the empty periods in my data set with 0s.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you. Just btw, I take time to review this in depth and learn from it, so thank you for teaching me this bit by bit, much appreciated. Finally, how would I get it to be capped to a 12 month period? So, right now, the periods stretch as far as 202113 since it doesn't recognize that we want a max of 12 periods (as in (right(period),2) should be max 12 after which the thousand increment moves from 2021 to 2022).

Comment: @DVEF see my edited answer.

Comment: A true angel, thank you. It is the optimal outcome and super fast even on a large data set.

Comment: @DVEF for this sample data: `(Period,ID,Instrument,Volume Balance)=(202102,1,A,4), (202103,1,A,8)` the result of the query is: `(Period,ID,Instrument,Volume Balance,Average Volume Balance)=(202102,1,A,4,2),(202103,1,A,8,6),(202104,1,A,0,4)` so the 1st row is the result for Feb = (4+0)/2

Comment: All good! Thanks! I see it in the raw data output of your query, it just doesn’t get included into the next step of the process in the db for some reason. Need to see why